# Binding an image to a dom element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an update function for a webcam. What it does so far is make an ajax call and serve the Url of the image. I have some problem binding the result (after the image is loaded) to the dom element (ccam).

```
function update() {
  $('#loading').show('fast');   

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'cam.php',
    data: 'img=<? echo $cam_id; ?>',
    timeout: 2000,
    cache: false,       
    success: function(data) {
      window.setTimeout(update, 20000);
       $('#currcam').hide();   
       $('#daycam').show(); 
       $('#loading').hide('fast');
       $('#ccam')
          .append(img)
          .append(html);
        // now show the image
        $(img).fadeIn();
    }, 
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $("#loading").html('Timeout contacting server..');
      window.setTimeout(update, 60000);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(update);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I can answer your question, please specify what is going on here:

```
$('#ccam').append(img).append(html);
```

What is in the `img` var and what is in the `html` var?